# Laravel 4 ssl subdomain redirects to main domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, laravel-4

I have installed laravel 4 in my subdomain app.domain.com and my main domain is on wordpress. My app.subdomain.com which is on laravel 4 framework works perfectly, but when i run it with ssl https://app.subdomain.com it will show the main domain content, the wordpress site.

I already have a wildcard certificate for the subdomain.

Is there any mods in .htaccess that I need to change?

Thanks.

My hosting is hostmonster. im using an addon domain with sub domain.

Here's my sub domain .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Main domain (wordpress)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that your main domain vhost overwrites the ssl subdomain of your project.
If you disable it, and restart apache, is your app still unreachable?

Because you don't need changes in Laravel and/or htaccess for this.

Comment: Hi @Rob, yes your right. I have tried changing the the .htaccess on my main domain. Seems like working but having problems on URL with www in my sub domain. Im using shared hosting. hostmonster.com

Comment: and also it blocks non https links

Comment: Can you update your post with information about your hosting, domain setup? I don't know how the controlpanel of your hosting works, but I think there is something wrong there.